# Is it possible :$\pi \sim{\frac{-\gamma}{(\sqrt{2}e^2-\gamma)^4}}-e^{-13}+2(17^{\frac13}-1)-2\phi^{-16}-\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(\frac{1}{17})^{2n+3}$?

Tags: approximation, pi

I have done many attempts to give another  approximation for $\pi$ I have got this

$$\pi \sim{\frac{-\gamma}{(\sqrt{2}e^2-\gamma)^4}}-e^{-13}+2(17^{\frac13}-1)-2\phi^{-16}-\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(\frac{1}{17})^{2n+3}$$, My question here : Is it possible to accept this approximation if it is not known before , probably my computation with [wolfram alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=-+%28sqrt%282%29*+e%5E2-euler+constant%29%5E%28-4%29*+euler+constant%2B%28-1%2Fe%5E13%29+%2B2*%28+17%5E%281%2F3%29-1%29-%282%29%2F%28golden+ratio%29%5E16-sum%28+%281%2F17%29%5E%282n%2B3%29%29%2C+n%3D1+to+infty+) not good however I have got an approximation with $10^{-7}$

**Note**:$\phi$ is the Golden ratio,$\gamma$ is the Euler -Mascheronni constant

Comment: @downvoter, show me the problem in that question, I think am in SE not MO

Comment: Is it possible for **who** to accept this approximation? What is the purpose of your approximation? It is far easier to memorise the 1st 8 digits of $\pi$ than to use your formula. If the accuracy is $10^{-7}$ then why are $e^{-13}$ and $\phi^{-16}$ in the formula?

Comment: Then try to remove out those terms and see the approximation how it would be , it would greater than 10^(-7)

Comment: @sammygerbil, you should know that 0.0000005 is not the same with 0.0000049999

Comment: @sammygerbil, before doing downvote at a least you should respect the work and effort  of others and u must know that I spent a huge of time to do that  , Really am confused where is the Role of community here , I accept the downvote only from the person who is an expert in the domain.

Comment: It is not a useful question. The formula is not a useful approximation. It does not provide any mathematical insight into the nature of $\pi$. The rules in this forum allow anyone to vote, not only experts. If you think your formula is useful then prove it.

Comment: In which side is not useful ? what is the definution of "useful question at u " ?  many known presented formula for pi are presented using other known constants , The useful approximation of pi no one even now come up to it , which is the connection between pi and e for which pi+e and e/pi being rational or irrational ? I think it is a humbel attemp which you should respect it before me , Thanks in advanced

Comment: @sammygerbil, And in the same time this is not a question of downvote since I showed my efforts in computation ,and I asked people if it is accepted or not  ?

Comment: @sammygerbil, see the below answer

Answer (score 0):

*This too long for comments.*

Be sure that I fully respect your work but when you look at the value of the different terms you introduced
$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
  \frac{-\gamma}{(\sqrt{2}e^2-\gamma)^4}    &   -0.0000607619504779 \\
  -e^{-13}                                  &   -0.0000022603294070 \\
  2 \left(\sqrt[3]{17}-1\right)             &   +3.1425631813164707 \\
 -2\phi^{-16}                               &   -0.0009062077075697 \\
  -\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(\frac{1}{17})^{2n+3} &   -0.0000007067417509 \\
\text{total}                                &   +3.1415932445872653 \\
\pi                                         &   +3.1415926535897932
\end{array}
\right)$$

So, the very interesting part is $ 2 \left(\sqrt[3]{17}-1\right)$.

Working $2 \left(\sqrt[3]{17}-1\right)-\pi$, we could find
$$\pi \sim 2 \left(\sqrt[3]{17}-1\right)-\frac{81\ 3^{34/45} \log ^{\frac{283}{90}}(3)}{8000\ 2^{13/90} e^{39/10} \log^{\frac{13}{9}}(2)}=3.141592653589793238461944$$ which is correct for $22$ decimal places (but which does present much interest).

Currently, using CAS, we can make so good approximations !

For example, working your problem of $\pi$, I found that, using only whole numbers, a good approximation of it is the reciprocal of the real root of the simple cubic $$31352 x^3-28993 x^2+53597 x-15134=0$$
$$\pi\sim\frac{94056}{28993+2 \sqrt{4200525383} \sinh \left(\frac{1}{3} \sinh
   ^{-1}\left(\frac{5960683043029}{4200525383 \sqrt{4200525383}}\right)\right)}$$ which gives $20$ exact significant figures (does this show any interest ?).

In the same spirit
$$\frac{248359849 \binom{e}{e!}+250062517 \binom{e!}{e}}{485577274}$$ gives $25$ significant digits.

Comment: Why is any of this of any greater interest than $22/7$ or $355/113$?

Comment: @sammygerbil. Be sure I fully agree with you (I think I wrote it in more diplomaic terms).

Comment: @sammygerbil, look [her](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=2%2817%5E%281%2F3%29-1%29-22%2F7)

Comment: @zeraouliarafik. This is what I wrote : the interesting part is  $2 \left(\sqrt[3]{17}-1\right) $

Comment: @Claude Leibovici                Is this part known before , what you can suggest to me to do with this  however this is not a rational number ?